# How do I prevent an enum with a generic parameter from 'propagating' to structs it's used in?

Tags: generics, rust

An enum that I'm writing contains variants which require generic parameters, but this enum is going to be changing types frequently (it's being used as an app state), so it wouldn't make sense to add it as a parameter to the main struct - I want the app to work for all variants of an enum. Effectively I need a more 'generic' generic.

Code:

```rust
enum WkResponse<T /* I want to constrain the type here according to Resources*/ > {
    User(UserResponse),
    Resource(ResourceResponse<T>),
    Summary(SummaryResponse),
    Pages(PagesResponse),
    Collection(CollectionResponse<T>),
}

pub enum Status {
    None,
    InProgress,
    Done(WkResponse),
}

pub struct KaniSabi /*Adding <T> here would mean the app would only work for one variant*/ {
    current_menu: Menus,
    first_opening: bool,
    api_key: String,
    net_status: Arc<Mutex<Status>>, 
    client: WanikaniClient,           
}
//All the possible values T could take
enum Resources {
    Assignment(Assignment),
    LevelProgression(LevelProgression),
    Reset(Reset),
    Review(Review),
    ReviewStatistic(ReviewStatistic),
    SpacedRepetitionSystem(SpacedRepetitionSystem),
    StudyMaterial(StudyMaterial),
    Subject(Subject),
    VoiceActor(VoiceActor),
}
```

For reference, I am using the [wanikani-rs](https://crates.io/crates/wanikani-rs) crate.

Comment: I don't understand, why don't you just use `Resources` as type. (nit: don't pluralize it, it should be `Resource`)

Comment: @cafce25 I feel very stupid right now. That solved it - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply replacing T with Resources fixed it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).